# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I'm trying to create simple internal messaging service for that i have used devise for authentication so i have users table. I have created a messages table for messages and a join table called messages_users. I want to use has_many through association so my associations are like this:-

user.rb :-

```
has_many :sent_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "user_id"
has_many :message_users
has_many :received_messages, through: :message_users, source: :message
```

message.rb:-

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :message_users
has_many :receivers, through: :message_users, source:  :user
```

message_user.rb :-

```
class MessageUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :message
end
```

and schema.rb :-

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130912100741) do

create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
  t.text     "subject"
  t.text     "body",       limit: 2147483647
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "messages_users", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer "user_id",    null: false
  t.integer "message_id", null: false
end

add_index "messages_users", ["message_id"], name: "index_messages_users_on_message_id",       using: :btree
add_index "messages_users", ["user_id"], name: "index_messages_users_on_user_id", using: :btree 
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "confirmation_token"
  t.datetime "confirmed_at"
  t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
  t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
  t.integer  "failed_attempts",        default: 0
  t.string   "unlock_token"
  t.datetime "locked_at"
  t.string   "authentication_token"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "provider"
  t.string   "uid"
  t.string   "name"
end

add_index "users", ["authentication_token"], name: "index_users_on_authentication_token", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "users", ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "users", ["unlock_token"], name: "index_users_on_unlock_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

It works fine when i use user_object.sent_messages but when i use user_object.received_messages it gives me **Mysql2::Error: Table 'to_do.message_users' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM
message_users
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'to_do.message_users' doesn't exist** error. I want to use has_many through only and not habtm. There were a couple of questions here on stackoverflow but none of them solved my issue so any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried renaming the table as I mentioned in answer yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails, we rely on "convention over configuration" to define a lot of the magic here. What is happening here is there's just some confusion over the pluralization of the "through" model.

Give this a try:

user.rb

```
has_many :sent_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "user_id"
has_many :messages_users
has_many :received_messages, through: :messages_users, source: :message
```

message.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :messages_users
has_many :receivers, through: :messages_users, source:  :user
```

messages_user.rb

```
class MessagesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :message
end
```

schema.rb - same as you had it with "create_table messages_users"...

Essentially, in Rails the convention is that:

- Model name must always be "Singular" (ie. MessagesUser)
- Database and collection names will always be "Pluralized" (ie. messages_users)

The confusing part of this is that your model name is a concatenation of two words and so probably the fact that one of them is pluralized and the other isn't was confusing. You can either leave it like this, or simply use one word to define the "through" model.

Try saying out in words something like "User has many Messages through Inbox". In which case your "through" model can be called Inbox (with a plural of Inboxes).

Either way, it will work as long as you follow convention :) hope this helps!

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh  ahh sorry my bad..but still it didn't solve the error

Comment: provide the class name and foreign key to the receive_messages

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh i might be wrong as i'm quite new to rails but doesn't source option does that for us...i had earlier tried passing class_name and foreign_key options without source and it gave me something like nosourcemethod error

Comment: This may be a silly question but did you run rake db:migrate after creating the message_users migration?

Comment: not able to figure out the actual check what query rails try to run and run the same in mysql. and try to figure out the error

Comment: @derekyau wouldn't the class name would be MessageUser as we are using message_users in assosiation? I know to have messages_users table i need to have class name MessagesUser..just a little confused anyways i replaced it with MessagesUser and now it gives me LoadError: Unable to autoload constant MessageUser expected /app/models/message_user.rb to define it

Comment: Okay - let me edit my solution again, and perhaps it will be more clear hold on.

Comment: @derekyau now its giving NameError: uninitialized constant User::MessagesUser

Comment: hmm... I just built this project from scratch and it seemed to work no problem. It seems to be looking for your MessagesUser under the namespace of User:: - this I'm not sure why is happening. Can you make sure your model's code match the ones I have above and see if the problem still occurs? Make sure that all the models are in the model folder and not nested under models/user for example. So far, I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: @derekyau got it.. i forget to change file name to messages_user.rb. Its working now..thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would only have two models for this User and Messages.

In messages I would give two fields sender_id and received_id.